# Convert multiple level string to jsonobject cause java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, json

I am using Java 7 with org.json-20120521.jar to convert json string to JSONObject.
Then the object will be used in another method

My json string contain multiple levels.
When I parse the string, error message will be thrown as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.CharacterDataLatin1.digit(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Character.digit(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Character.digit(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.JSONObject.stringToValue(JSONObject.java:1279)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:389)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:212)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:363)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:212)
                             ...
```

Follow are my example code

1. My JSON String : http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/454634/test.txt
2. Main Java Code:

> NOTE: I have tried to test my json string with another libraries such
>   as gson-2.2.4.jar and json-simple-1.1.1.jar, both libraries work fine.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

/**
 *
 */
public class TestJSON
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FileInputStream stream = null;
        try
        {
            stream = new FileInputStream(new File("test.txt"));
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            char[] buffer = new char[8192];
            int read;
            while ((read = reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0)
            {
                builder.append(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            String str = builder.toString();

            convertByGSON(str);
            convertByJSON(str);
            convertBySimple(str);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                stream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private static void convertByJSON(String str)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
            System.out.println("Finish1");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Error e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void convertByGSON(String str)
    {
        try
        {
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonElement jsonE = parser.parse(str);
            JsonObject json = jsonE.getAsJsonObject();
            System.out.println("Finish2");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Error e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void convertBySimple(String str)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            org.json.simple.JSONObject parsed = (org.json.simple.JSONObject)parser.parse(str);
            System.out.println("Finish3");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Error e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

earist

Comment: Please include the JSON in your question. If it is big then trim it to the minimal JSON that still causes this error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your JSON is too 'deep'. There are too many nested properties. The org.json parser gets the StackOverflowError because there are too many recursive method calls.

Even if you change your json library, you can still run in same problem when you try to traverse your parsed object recursively.

For example if you try to pretty print the object with Gson

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(json);
```

the same with json-simple:

```
String json = parsed.toJSONString();
```

To solve the issue you should either reconsider the JSON structure or increase the JRE stack  size f.x. -Xss4m